# KDE's media controls api

Tags: kde, api, mediaplayer

KDE has a feature called "media controls", with which I can control media from the lock screen.  I would like to add this feature to a music software I'm working on.  I tried to find the necessary API (or a hint to it) in VLC (a software that implements this feature) and the web, but on both I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [MPRIS](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/) (Media Player Remote Interfacing Specification), the standard D-BUS interface to control media players. It is DE-agnoistic, i.e not only bound to KDE. If your player support it, any DE can feature control for your player. Read more in

- [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MPRIS)
- [KDE wiki](https://community.kde.org/MPRIS)